# jQuery - Passing data from a jQuery function to a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to pass data from a function to a specific div, but I can't seem to be able to get this to work. I'm making a gallery viewer and I just want to pass the counter that I use to show the pictures and the total number of files for each gallery in the page.

Here is the code:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.photoset').each(function () {
        $(this).data('counter', 0);
        $items = $(this).find('img')
        $(this).data('numItems', $items.length);
    });



    var showCurrent = function (photoset) {
        $items = photoset.find('img');
        var counter = photoset.data('counter');
        var numItems = $items.length;
        var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter % numItems);

        $items.fadeOut();
        $items.eq(itemToShow).fadeIn();
    };

    $('.photoset').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var photoset = $(this);
        var pWidth = photoset.innerWidth();
        var pOffset = photoset.offset();
        var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
        if (pWidth / 2 > x) {
            photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') - 1);
            if (photoset.data('counter') < 0)
                photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('numItems') - 1);
            showCurrent(photoset);
        } else {
            photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') + 1);
            if (photoset.data('counter') > photoset.data('numItems') - 1)
                photoset.data('counter', 0);
            showCurrent(photoset);
        }
        $(this).text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'))
    });
});
```

**Html Razor**

```
<div class="container">
    @{ var i = 10; }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NomeGaleria)
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center"><div class="nav-informer"></div></div></div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="photoset center-block">


                    @{ var item2 = item.FilePaths;}
                    @for (var k = 0; k < Enumerable.Count(item2); k++)
                {
                        <br />
                        <img src="~/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem2 => item2[k].FileName)" style="@(k != 0 ? "display: none" : "" ) " />
                        <br />
                    }

                </div>

        </div>

    }
</div>
```

So I'm trying to use this code

```
$(this).text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'))
```

to pass the data to the "nav-informer" div, but it just won't work. Does anyone knows what to do in this case? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm very new to jQuery.

**UPDATE**

Here is the rendered HTML page:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            <br />
            Galeria Um
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center"><div class="nav-informer"></div></div></div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="photoset center-block">



                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/572fdd6b-13eb-48d2-8940-23da73e056c0.JPG" style=" " />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/018a55be-a8a7-4412-8415-1678d01eb6a2.JPG" style="display: none " />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/e5b0bdcb-d517-49a5-818b-245d46c0a0d9.JPG" style="display: none " />
                    <br />

            </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            <br />
            Galeria Dois
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center"><div class="nav-informer"></div></div></div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="photoset center-block">



                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/fdc2e9fd-978a-4150-87af-483e34f68798.JPG" style=" " />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/b17d169d-e5ed-45cd-9901-1d9dc294c873.JPG" style="display: none " />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/3ad1ae20-7102-4d69-b658-7b3d8cbfb9e8.JPG" style="display: none " />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/4ef03a84-da00-4f93-b3a2-839ac2ec9ac2.JPG" style="display: none " />
                    <br />

            </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since you're new to jQuery, the use of `$(this)` basically means "the element that I've started the process with" which in your case is `.photoset`.  So `$(this) = $('.photoset')`

If you want to make that line of text go into your `.nav-informer` div, you need to change `$(this)` to `$('.nav-informer')`

```
$('.nav-informer').text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'));
```

UPDATE

So it seems you need to traverse through the hierarchy. Is each 'gallery' a `.container`?  If so, try this:

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('.nav-informer').text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'));
```

`.closest()` traverses up through the hierarchy trying to find the closest **parent** of the element you start with.  (in our case `$(this)`).

'.find()' does the opposite, it goes down through the hierarchy to find the first instance of the element in question from the point before.

Add them together and what I like to do is `.closest()` to the parent of the element you're trying to find and `.find()` the element after that.  I feel like doing `.parents()`, `.children()` and `.siblings()` gets messy.

**UPDATE 2**

Alright, I see now - The way you're exporting each gallery may get a bit dicey eventually, and if possible, I would suggest containing your gallery and informer into the same container, but if you're going to leave it like this, try this:

```
$(this).closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.nav-informer').text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'));
```

So, using `.parent()` will traverse only a single parent, where if you needed to go farther up, you can use `.parents()` (with an S) or my favorite `.closest()`.  Then, once you reach the level you need to go, you can use `.siblings()`, or in our case, since your `.nav-informer` is **always** in the `.row` before your `.photoset`, you need to use `.prev()`.  This will select the div written directly before the div you are currently, at the same level.

Check [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fpyrm81/) to see a quick example.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering! I've tried this approach before, but since I generate a new     $('nav-informer') for each gallery, I end up changing all of them with this method. I need to change only the gallery I'm currently on. The jQuery function only targets the current gallery when I click it, so that's why I've tried using $(this).

Comment: @n.ab, I think I understand now,  I've updated my answer

Comment: Each gallery is a photoset div, I've tried updating with your answer and replacing '.container' to '.photoset' but it didn't work. The text does not appear in the page.

Comment: @n.ab, I see, how many `.nav-informer`s are there? Is there one per photoset?

Comment: @n.ab, Can you update your question with an example of the rendered HTML with multiple photosets and multiple nav-informers?

Comment: @n.ab, Thank you!  I think this last update will do it.  The way you have your HTML exporting might get a little dicey, and I'd suggest making each 'set' of informer and photoset contained in a single container.

Comment: Thanks again! Tried this new method but still isn't showing up in the end result. Should I try to put them in a single container and try the first answer of yours?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` to make sure the text you're trying to input is actually inputting? Or made sure in console there are no errors?

Comment: The text worked when I tried the first method you suggested, using `$('.nav-informer')` instead of `$(this)` but it targeted all the informer when i clicked on the image to go to the next image.

Comment: @n.ab, I see.  Ok, so if the text works, I changed the last update to try and see if `.closest()` works better than `.parent()`.  If that doesn't work, then I'd suggest putting those things into a container.  I will make a fiddle to test this out

Comment: @n.ab, I've added a fiddle to show it sort of working

Comment: hey! Sorry, had to go to bed yesterday. I've seen the fiddle and that it works, but I can't seem to manage to get it working on my page, don't have a clue why ):

Comment: I've just now seen that appears to have an error on the console: `Index:56 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).prev(...).find(...).$ is not a function` do you have any idea why this might been happening?

Comment: changed just had to remove `$('.nav-informer')` and now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot, really :) Just one thing, the text only appears after I click on the image and it calls the javascript function, is there a way for the text to appear right after I run for the first time?

Comment: @n.ab, Great! I'm glad it worked!  If you want your code to run on load, you'll have to take it out of the `.click()` function.  You can either copy all of your code into the `$('.photoset').each(...);` function or you can change your `.click()` to `.each()` and it will do the same thing.  by putting the code in `.each()` it will ensure you can use `$(this)` for 'photoset'.

Comment: Working beautifuly now. Have to study a lot to get to your level :) thanks again, have a nice weekend.

Comment: @n.ab, It took me a bit to get here, but it all starts making sense quickly.  I still don't know as much as I should though! I'm glad it works!